# Bluetooth human device interface for reading digital input channels

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, bluetooth, externalinterface, hardware-interface

An idea is to make Win Mobile phone become super alarm for car.
Now I am searching for devices simalr to [Velleman interface board](http://www.velleman.eu/distributor/products/view/?id=351346), but I need device which
can be connected to mobile device using bluetooth trough compact framework and C#.
I need digital inputs for caching real events such as engine started or door opened. Is there a way to interface mobile device with outside world using inputs with voltage.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need a custom piece of hardware that will hook in to the ECM of the car. Most cars use the ODB II standard interface.

This hardware would need to have a bluetooth chip on it, and communicate the ODB II signals through the bluetooth controller. But notice there is no standard for "door is ajar" etc. The ECM deals with engine timing ignition etc.

Your win mobile phone would need a driver to catch those events after it has paired with the hardware chip. You can use the "The Windows Embedded Source Tools for Bluetooth Technology" to do this on the mobile phone side.