# Oscilloscope api for compact framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, oscilloscope

Few days ago I where searching for [human interface for mobile devices.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910637/bluetooth-human-device-interface-for-reading-digital-input-channels) but all bluetooth devices
are pretty messy and hard to implement.

Question are: "Is there open source, or free library for making Oscilloscope on WinMobile platform.
As my interface is not going to be human, I will try to make some kind of buzzer which is going to send sound commands to WinMobile device, at other side WinMoilbe device should be able to read frequency of buzzer tone and recognize command.

### [Moved to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978505/compact-framework-voice-recognize-api-or-library)

> ```
> So far my research telling me that there is no free library for voice recognize.
> Is this still a case, (because all post I found is old few years).
> ```

Comment: There's a lot going on in this question, so you might want to distill it down to one question, or separate questions.

Comment: @cracke I edited my question and split to tow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to read the frequency is fairly simple.  You need to use the [waveInXxxx APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909811.aspx) to capture the incoming sound, then you can run [an FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) on that data to determine frequency.

[MSDN has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx) of using the waveInXxxx functions from the CF.
The SDF has [two FFT algorithms](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/9bc50742-5a8d-e633-7db3-5d0ef829f949.htm).