# Compact framework voice recognize API or library

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, voice-recognition

So far my research telling me that there is no free library for voice recognize.
Is this still a case, (because all post I found is old few years).
Is there sample app, or anything that I can start with If I want to make my WinMobile C# app be able
to recognize Voice from input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only library I'm aware of that works with Windows Mobile and the Compact Framework is [Chant](http://chant.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.microsoft.com/speech/developers.aspx

Microsoft offer free implementations, but they aren't available on [Windows Mobile](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/84251e0e-3956-479a-bdad-2d53ed2da19d).